# Why is this working?

Tags: javascript, iframe

I have written some simple javascript to change the content of an iframe according to the input of a field. After hours of attempts, I have managed to get it working; however I didn't really understand why I should put the "return true" and "return false" at the end of my search function. Thank you in advance!

```
function search(){
    var course=document.getElementById("field");
    if(course.value!=""){
        if(course.value!="Course code (e.g. COMP1004)"){
            var target=document.getElementById("frame");
            target.src=course.value + ".php";
            return false;
        }
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

```
<input id="field" name="field" type="text"></input>
<input id="searchButton" name="searchButton" type="button"value="Search"onclick="search()"></input>
```

Comment: The `return`s do nothing in your current code

Comment: Are you sure you didn't have your function bound to a submit element ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really need to, since you are calling the function without expecting any value. And even if you write `onclick = return search()` you have no default action to prevent, since your input has `type="button"`

Answer (score 0):

When you trigger a javascript function using onclick (depending on the browser), the actual functionality of the click can be prevented by returning false. So if you click on a button and return true (or nothing) the actual click will be triggered and e.g. load a new page. If you return false, the original function of the button will not be called ...